# HTML Javascript - Download

Tags: javascript, html, download, three.js, base64

I have implemented a 3d model with three.js and i want to download the base64 png image on user's click. I have already done that but my problem is this: I want the download to start after 1 second because i want to change the background-color of the model first, from black to white. So the code works if the download starts immediately but in a setTimeout() function it won't. Here is what it works:

```
    renderer.setClearColor("white");
    setTimeout(
      function(){
            window.open(renderer.domElement.toDataURL("image/png"),"Final");
            renderer.setClearColor("black");
      }
   ,500);
   document.getElementById("bt").download  ="file.png";
   $(this).attr('href',renderer.domElement.toDataURL("image/png"));
```

and here is what does not work

```
       renderer.setClearColor("white");    
       setTimeout(
         function(){
            document.getElementById("bt").download="file.png";
            $(this).attr('href',renderer.domElement.toDataURL("image/png"));
            renderer.setClearColor("black");
         }
        ,500);
```

Comment: Why do you need a setTimeout to change the background colour? Can't you just call your render function after setting the background colour, but before calling toDataUrl ?